# How can I tell if a django RelatedManager .add() found that the object was already added?

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following code in a post_save function

```
@receiver(post_save)
def update_parent_location(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
list_of_models = ('A', 'B', 'C')

if sender.__name__ in list_of_models:
    groups = instance.group_set.all()
    fields_to_update = tuple(field.lower() for field in list_of_models)

    for field in fields_to_update:
        parent = getattr(instance, field, None)
        if parent is not None:
            parent.groups.add(*groups)
            parent.save()
```

How would I know if the

```
parent.groups.add(*groups)
```

part actually added a new object or failed silently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the groups count before and after, to see if anything changed:

```
...
num_groups = parent.groups.count()
parent.groups.add(*groups)
if parent.groups.count() > num_groups:
   # Something was added
   parent.save()
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I would have thought there is an in-built way to do this though.